# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check NodeJS/Heroku/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I'm using an Express app on Heroku. I try to make a RESTful request to it from another NodeJS app.

Here's a snippet from the Heroku app, called `app.js`:

```
var express=        require("express");
app.get("/results",function(req,res){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
});
```

And here's a snippet from an app I run locally, `local-app.js`:

```
var request=        require("superagent");
var req=            request.get("http://url-to-app-js.com?query=1").set(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://url-to-app-js.com",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With"
);
req.end(function(err,res){
    // do things
});
```

When I run `local-app.js`, I got this error in my browser console: `esponse to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

I know that I could run the browser, Chromium, with certain security settings turned off, but I need to be able to run this without doing so.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: did u ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` are **response** headers. They shouldn't appear in the request at all.

By adding non-standard headers you make the request a preflighted request instead of a simple request. (You might be doing something else that makes it a preflighted request, but the extra headers definitely do not help).

A preflighted request sends a OPTIONS request to find out if it is allowed by CORS before making the request (GET in this case) you actually want to make.

You are only setting the CORS response headers when you receive a GET request. Since you don't respond with them to the OPTIONS request, the browser refuses to make the GET request.

Comment: What would I need to change to correct this? (I'm not very familiar with this sort of header...)

Comment: Start by **not setting the headers I said you shouldn't set**

Comment: If that doesn't work, then wrote some code to handle the OPTIONS request.

Comment: Are you saying to remove them from `app.js` or `local-app.js`? Or both?